# Помогите с округлением без библиотеки math в си

Tags: c, округление

float_int_run Бегуны
Два бегуна бегают по круговой гаревой дорожке. Тренировку они начали одновременно.

Первый бегун пробежал всего

0<n<1000 кругов.

Первый бегун бежит со скоростью

v, второй со скоростью kv, где 0<k≤1.

Сколько раз бегуны встретились за время тренировки на дорожке?

Дано: целое число n и, через пробел, дробное число k.

Найти: целое число - количество встреч.

Пример: при вводе 0.5 программа должна вывести 1, т.е. округлить в большую сторону

Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n;
    float k;
    scanf("%d", &n, &k);
    int krug_2 = n * k;
    int meet = n - krug_2;
    printf("%d", meet);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что-то у вас название вопроса с содержимым не бьется.

Answer (score 1):

Ну ведь вам же сказано, что `k` между 0 и 1, что это дробное число. И читать его нужно не как целое (впрочем, вы даже этого не делали, вообще его не читая...), а как `float`:

```
float k;
scanf("%d %f", &n, &k);
```

А дальше все просто, как вы и написали, считаем и выводим целую часть `n*(1.-k)`:

```
int meet = n*(1.-k);
printf("%d", meet);
```